# Can't get a valid response from a webpage containing json data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to get response from a webpage. The data in that webpage are in `json` format. However, when I try like below I get an error. Can somebody give me any workaround as to how I can get a valid response?

Here is my failure attempt:

```
import requests
import json

URL = "https://www.sandicormls.com/agent/AgentSearch?officeSortOption=name&_=1516998894917&_keywordsAll=&officeLocation=&sortOption=rndsrt&_keywordsAgentName=&page=&typeIn=Realtor%2CBroker%2COwner%2COffice+Manager%2CAppraiser&searchMode=agent&officeName="
res = requests.get(URL,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
print(res.json())
```

This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\new_line_one.py", line 34, in <module>
    print(res.json())
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 892, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: well if the response is includes non-JSON stuff with it, it's going to cause issues

Comment: For that url I get `416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable - The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do` which explains why the `JSONDecoder` is complaining that the json is empty (error at line 1 column 1 is usually empty data).

Comment: Is there anything I can do with this url? I mean, anything to reach the data?

Comment: It looks like it might be a 'single use' url - once you've got the data, it won't work again for future requests.

Comment: No problem getting that data for me, with exactly the code you post, multiple times. What is the value of `res.status_code`?

Comment: The response status is `200` @Nathan Vērzemnieks.

Comment: Hm. What apout `res.headers`?

Comment: This is what I get using `res.headers`   : `{'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Server': 'nginx', 'Edge-Control': 'no-store, bypass-cache', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Date': 'Sun, 28 Jan 2018 06:48:05 GMT', 'Content-Length': '759', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Expires': 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Surrogate-Control': 'no-store, bypass-cache'}`

Answer (score 0):

I just gave it a try and confirm that your code is fine as it works on my environment. Though, I run it on a Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) virtual machine.
You could check what data you are getting back

```
print(res.headers[‘content-type’])
```

or examine the content such as

```
print(res.text)
```